# Trying to make a weight converter that converts a weight in kg to stones, pounds and ounces- Java

Tags: java, converters

I would like to create my own Converter class which will take an input weight from terminal and convert it to stones, pounds and ounces. I wondered how I would go about this?

I will create a method within this class called converter, and I wondered whether all my calculations should be within this method or whether I need more methods? I am anxious I haven't gotten the right idea of implementing my own methods yet.

also, would I put the input weight (using EasyIn library)as a parameter for this method?

Any examples would be much appreciated!
Many thanks!

Comment: Is this schoolwork?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Start reading [The Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying the console in eclipse or other IDE, than look at system.in

```
class MyProg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Printing the file passed in:");
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack overflow. Luckily, all you need to do is write some basic methods that perform math.

```
public double convertStone();
{
     // conversion code here
}
```

And you can repeat that for each value you need. For the conversion code, you only need to convert the actual math for, say, KG to LBS into code like so:

```
kgToLbs = kg * 2.21;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would it work to do the full conversion within one method?
ie


 public double convert(){ 

 weightInStone= (weightInKg*35.274)/((16*14);
remainingOuncesFromStone=(weightInKg*35.274)-((35.274*weightInStone)/(16*14)) ;
weightInPounds=(remainingOuncesFromStone/16) ;
 weightInOunces=(weightInKg*35.274)-weightInPounds;

}

and then how would this output to the user?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Yes, you can perform all conversions in one method. Just make sure you take an input for the method and return a value at the end.

Comment: ok, so the input would go as a parameter, and at the end how would I make it display in stones, pounds AND ounces? (Sorry I'm sure you must be cringing at my difficulty xD)

Comment: if you want to complete it all in one method, set the method return type to void instead of double, and simple System.out.println(); the variables!

Comment: you are brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

[java](/questions/tagged/java)I worked on a project similar to this one. What I did was I posed a question within the terminal asking which conversion they would like to do, which would then prompt some "if" statements that run the selected conversion. This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's useful if you're unsure about inputting your own methods.

```
        String selection;
        double weight, stones;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Print statements asking the user what conversion they would like to do
        selection = sc.nextLine();
            if(selection.equalsIgnoreCase("stones"))
            {
                //conversion
            }
            //etc
```